# Testing polymer project with backend running on other port/host

Tags: ajax, rest, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm building and polymer project that will be the frontend to an restapi.

Serving the frontend locally with `$ polymer serve` this starts the server on `http://127.0.0.1:8081`

My backend can run also locally `$ python -m swagger_server` and listens on : `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

I want to do ajax request with `iron-ajax`

```
  <iron-ajax auto id="ajax" url="http://localhost:8080/api/order" last-response="{{orders}}"></iron-ajax>
```

but the different port number makes it an cross-origin request:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/order. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.`

Also, this is just for testing; on the production server, the cross-origin problem will be solved with the webserver serving the frontend (on `/`) and also the backend (on `/api`). And before deploying I will have to delete all the `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and leave just the paths `/api/orders`

Comment: CORS need to be solved on server side. You will have to edit some headers so it accepts requests from different sites. I have never done this since in my company there are back-end programmers who do this but it took them always few minutes. Porpably something like this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342284/preflight-cors-issue-with-javascript-and-python-base-http-server

Comment: Solved https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ thanks. But this is just an temporary workaround, I still have to remember to delete the "http://127.0.01:8080" in all the `iron-ajax` elements, before deploying to the production.

Comment: yep that's another way, because cors is disabled on localhost. but as i said, you should read some articles about how to enable cors on python side and it will help you. Good to know for future projects :)